# Use parameter as var in c:set

Tags: jsp, tags, jstl

I am trying to make a tag that converts true/false to yes/no

I have the following tag

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@attribute name="bool"%>
<%@attribute name="varName"%>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${bool}">
        <c:set var="${varName}" value="Yes"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="${varName}" value="No"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

It is used like this

```
<ecas:yesNo bool="${propCrse.topicsCourse}" varName="proposedText"/>
```

However when it is rendered the app throws the following error

```
ERROR 02 Sep 2016 08:02:01,086 errorPage  - /WEB-INF/tags/yesNo.tag (line: 7, column: 8) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute var does not accept any expressions
```

Comment: That is true: According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute var does not accept any expressions

Answer (score 0):

You could use just

```
${propCrse.topicsCourse?"Yes":"No"}
```

or

```
<c:set var="proposedText" value='${propCrse.topicsCourse?"Yes":"No"}'/>
```